# Why is a function more accurate if $x$ is small enough for truncated Taylor Series?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

I've noted the following thing in my lecture notes:[image]

And I can't seem to come up with a good enough explanation for why this is a good approximation if $x$ is small enough. Does that mean if you have an interval $[0,x]$ where $x$ is small enough it will show the shape of the function relatively accurately? What I'm trying to get at here is does the size of $x$ indicate the interval we're considering the function in, and if so, why? It's just a point.

Comment: If $x$ is small enough, the neglected terms are small. In appropriate circumstances, the first derivative gives a linear approximation, the second derivative a quadratic etc. The terms ignored are $x^4$ etc which will be small in comparison with $x^3$, and certainly in comparison with the leading term $1$, provided $x$ is small enough.

Comment: Because the powers of very small numbers is much smaller than the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what happens to the last term as a function of $x$, and recall that the sum of all the neglected terms is smaller that this term (as long as $|x| \leq 1/2$).

If $|x| < 1/2$, $|x^3| < 1/8$.

If $|x| = 1/10$, $|x^3| < 1/1000$.

If $|x| = 1/100$, $|x^3| < 10^{-6}$.

The sum of the neglected terms goes as the cube of $x$, so for moderately small $x$ it is very good indeed.